# Copy multiple files in parallel

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnu-parallel

I have a directory which has some 10000 files and I wanted to copy those files in parallel.  Since, I have 4 processors, I wanted to see if I could copy four files at the same time in parallel. I don't know how I can achieve this with `GNU Parallel`. I don't even know if this is possible. So help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is copy files limited by the processor? It seems more likely it's limited by disk read speed, and that copying in parallel will do pretty little.

Answer (score 0):

```
find src -type f |
  parallel cp {} dst/
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with a similar problem needing to copy many directories and files from a local block storage device (AWS EBS) to a mounted NFS device (EFS). Since this is in the cloud, resources like CPU, network and IO can be scaled so speeding up the copy process can also be parallelised, but linux commands like cp and rsync can't take advantage of this.

I recently found the fpsync command that combines the fpart and rsync commands to parallelise copying which provides the ability to speed up this kind of copying tremendously.

On Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install fpart
sudo fpsync -n X /src /dst
```

Where X is the number of parallel processes.

The docs for this utility are here: https://www.fpart.org/fpsync/
...and the original AWS blog post is here: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/efs-copy-data-in-parallel which also has some other options as well.